# How would one go about making a BaseAdapter ListView to open another activity on row click?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onclick, baseadapter

I followed the persons tutorials on YouTube I got everything to work. But, the tutorial person did not explain how to link the BaseAdapter listView to open another activity when you click a row.

here is what i have MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.baseadapter;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countries);
    list.setAdapter(new VivzAdapter(this));
}


class SingleRow{

    String title;
    String description;
    int image;
    SingleRow(String title,String description, int image){

        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
}

class VivzAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;
    VivzAdapter(Context c){

        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

        Resources res = c.getResources();

        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        String[] description = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);
        int [] images = {
                R.drawable.union_europea,
                R.drawable.espania,
                R.drawable.finlandia,
                R.drawable.francia,
                R.drawable.irlanda,
                R.drawable.italia,
                R.drawable.malta,
                R.drawable.monaco,
                R.drawable.portugal,
                R.drawable.rusia
        };
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            list.add(new SingleRow(title[i],description[i],images[i]));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewGroup,false);

        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

        title.setText(temp.title);
        description.setText(temp.description);
        image.setImageResource(temp.image);


        return row;
    }

}
```

}

the strings.xml file

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">BaseAdapter</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>


<string-array name="titles">
    <item>Meme 1</item>
    <item>Meme 2</item>
    <item>Meme 3</item>
    <item>Meme 4</item>
    <item>Meme 5</item>
    <item>Meme 6</item>
    <item>Meme 7</item>
    <item>Meme 8</item>
    <item>Meme 9</item>
    <item>Meme 10</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="description">
    <item>This is description 1</item>
    <item>This is description 2</item>
    <item>This is description 3</item>
    <item>This is description 4</item>
    <item>This is description 5</item>
    <item>This is description 6</item>
    <item>This is description 7</item>
    <item>This is description 8</item>
    <item>This is description 9</item>
    <item>This is description 10</item>

</string-array>
```

If anyone  could please at least give me a few tips on how to make my listview to open another activity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You implement the onClickListener on the `row` view to open another activity

```
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ACTIVITY.class);
         getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

hope this helps